# How can i simplifies this objective C code for IOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new in development and to do some stuff i write sometimes a really strange code.. For example, in this case, i've made a scrollview for showing an horizontal number list from 1 to 40. Each number is a button. I wan't that when the user click on a number, the background image of this button change, and when he click on another one, the background of the new button also change (but the first button come back to his initial state). Like on a tab bar...

To do that i've made the same code 40 times (for each button) :

```
- (IBAction)Bouton1:(id)sender  {

UIImage *buttonImageOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif-rollover.png"];
UIImage *buttonImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif.png"];
[sender setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOn forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_button2 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button3 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button4 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button5 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button6 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button7 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button8 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button9 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button10 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button11 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button12 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button13 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button14 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button15 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button16 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button17 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button18 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button19 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button20 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button21 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button22 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button23 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button24 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button25 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button26 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button27 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button28 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button29 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button30 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button31 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button32 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button33 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button34 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button35 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button36 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button37 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button38 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button39 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button40 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)Bouton2:(id)sender {  

UIImage *buttonImageOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif-rollover.png"];
UIImage *buttonImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif.png"];
[sender setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOn forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_button1 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[_button2 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button3 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button4 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button5 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button6 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button7 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button8 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button9 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button10 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button11 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button12 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button13 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button14 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button15 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button16 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button17 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button18 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button19 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button20 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button21 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button22 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button23 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button24 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button25 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button26 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button27 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button28 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button29 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button30 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button31 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button32 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button33 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button34 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button35 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button36 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button37 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button38 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button39 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button40 setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

So when i click on a button, it change all the others.. How can i write a better code?

Comment: 1) Putting all the buttons in an array. 2)calling only one ibaction and looping the buttons, using the sender parameter to detect the only button that will behave differently than the others... I guess it would be better...

Comment: If I understand the question this sounds like a job for UITableView rather than UIScrollView

Comment: good luck on getting the UITableView to scrolls horizontal ;-)

Comment: One IBOutletCollection typed to UIButton or whatever type you use for buttons.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Whoops! Probably should have read the question a bit more closely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can connect all buttons to the same `IBAction`, so you don't need to write the action 40 times. To simplify it even more you could to sth. like this:

You could connect all buttons to an `IBOutletCollection` let's say we call it `allButtons` which is an `NSArray` an modify your code like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender  {

    UIImage *buttonImageOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif-rollover.png"];
    UIImage *buttonImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif.png"];


    for (UIButton *button in self.allButtons)
    {  
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [sender setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me that I wanted to add IBOutletCollection to one of my projects.

Comment: This is perfect! I just test it and it works fine! I learned how to use IBOutletCollection and this is a big time saver! Thank you Tobi!

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array to store buttons:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *buttons;
```

Then init the array and store buttons in it dynamically:

```
self.buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
   // ...
   Button *button = [[Button alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
   button.tag = i;
   [self.buttons addObject:button];
}
```

Later, you can access any button by the tag (index):

```
int index = 25;
Button *button = [self.buttons objectAtIndex:index];
```

The `tag` in button tells which button is clicked by the user, for example, when you hooks a gesture recognizer or touch event to the button.

Comment: Only sane solution so far. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I would give each button a tag. Button number 1 gets tag 1 (don't use tag 0!. If you want to use zero indexed tags use 10000 till 100039), button number 40 gets tag 40

```
- (void)configureViewForActivatedButtonNumber:(NSInteger)activeButtonNumber {
    UIImage *buttonImageOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif-rollover.png"];
    UIImage *buttonImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif.png"];
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [self.scrollView viewWithTag:i];
        if (i != activeButtonNumber) {
            [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }       
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSInteger buttonTag = sender.tag;
    [self configureViewForActivatedButtonNumber:buttonTag];
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of a tag number, that's quite elegant... But couldn't it be messy when you're using tags for others objects ? For exemple, you'll need to reserve a range of tags to prevent having an object at 10041 when you need to add a new button ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the items in an array. Then you can loop through every item and set the background image.

```
UIImage *buttonImageOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif-rollover.png"];
UIImage *buttonImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fond-footer-motif.png"];

NSArray *buttons = @[sender, _button2, _button3, _button4, _button5, _button6, _button7];
for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Yes he will. But I find it more future proof. And makes your code much more readable.

Comment: There are a lot of approaches with each it's pros and cons.

Comment: 40 IBActions are more readable and future proof? I beg to differ. I would prefer "Don't repeat yourself" over "Write Everything Ten Thousand Times" ;-)

Comment: What I mean is, it could have only one IBAction instead of 40... Then by detecting who's the sender, he will be able to load the correct image.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch that's where we differ :P.

Comment: @H2CO3 what do you mean by segfault? Tried to look it up but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @app_ it's because you forgot the nil terminator at the end of your array declaration... I did the same mistake...

Comment: @AndyM I think you don't have to use nil at the end of the literal syntax. [http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Comment: @app_ My bad, you're right and H2CO3 is wrong. We don't need this nil. We would need it when using arrayWithObjects for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version :

```
for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [(UIButton *)subview setBackgroundImage:buttonImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Of course you would most likely need some other if check inside the loop. You could decide to set a tag id of some number to all the buttons on the view. You can do that quite easily in Interface Builder, by selecting all buttons, and set the Tag there.

This version is quite fast and works